# How to correctly import javascript function and use it into a node.js script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

so I have a time-stamp function in a javascript file that return a date that look like `MM/DD/YY`

I would like tom import what the function return into another script ( node.js) and display it whenever the script run.

But whenever I fire up the node.js program , I get something like : `[object Object]`, and I have no idea where this comes from ...

Here is the `timeStamp.js`

```
function timeStamp() {
    let now = new Date();
    let date = [ now.getMonth() + 1, now.getDate(), now.getFullYear() ];
    let time = [ now.getHours(), now.getMinutes(), now.getSeconds() ];
    let suffix = ( time[0] < 12 ) ? "AM" : "PM";
    time[0] = ( time[0] < 12 ) ? time[0] : time[0] - 12;
    time[0] = time[0] || 12;
    for ( var i = 1; i < 3; i++ ) {
        if ( time[i] < 10 ) {
            time[i] = "0" + time[i];
        }
    }
    return date.join("/") + " " + time.join(":") + " " + suffix;
}
```

and here is the `node.js` script

```
let io = require('socket.io').listen(process.env.port||5000);

var date = require('./timeStamp');

io.on('connection', function(socket) {

    console.log('Date is ...'+date);

    socket.on('data',function (data , callback) {
        console.log(`"${data}" was received ...`);
        callback(true);
    });
});
```

How can I fix this bug or what am I doing wrong or missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing: `module.exports = timeStamp;` without it, when using `require` an empty object will be exported, that's why you get [Object object]

```js
console.log('Date is...' + {});
```

Apart from that, you will need to call the date function, otherwise you will print the actual function code.

```
console.log('Date is...' + date());
```

```js
function timeStamp() {
    let now = new Date();
    let date = [ now.getMonth() + 1, now.getDate(), now.getFullYear() ];
    let time = [ now.getHours(), now.getMinutes(), now.getSeconds() ];
    let suffix = ( time[0] < 12 ) ? "AM" : "PM";
    time[0] = ( time[0] < 12 ) ? time[0] : time[0] - 12;
    time[0] = time[0] || 12;
    for ( var i = 1; i < 3; i++ ) {
        if ( time[i] < 10 ) {
            time[i] = "0" + time[i];
        }
    }
    return date.join("/") + " " + time.join(":") + " " + suffix;
}

// In node use module.exports here
// module.exports = timeStamp;

// This will print the function code
console.log('Date is...' + timeStamp); 

// This will print the correct date
console.log('Date is...' + timeStamp());
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `timeStamp` function to `exports` object then you'll be able to require it in any file you want. And this is how you do that

```
module.exports = timeStamp;
```

in your `timeStamp.js` file.

And this is how you'll call that function in your node script

```
var date = require('./timeStamp');
date();
```

Comment: Should module.exports be inside or outside timeStamp() function ?

Comment: No. After `timeStamp`'s definition i-e at the end of your file

Answer (score 2):

add `module.exports = timeStamp;` to the timeStamp.js file,
and then you'll need to do date() in the `console.log('Date is ...'+date() );` statement.